# Tmux doesn't use gnome-terminal color palette

Tags: text, colors, tmux

Tmux doesn't use gnome-terminal color palette

**Version**

Tmux - 3.1b

gnome-terminal - 2.31.3

[System color palettes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8HAb.png)

.zshrc

```
202 #export TERM=xterm-256color
203 #export TERM=gnome-256color
204 export TERM=screen-256color
205 #export TERM=screen-256color-bce
```

.tmux.conf

```
248 # Enable RGB colour if running in xterm(1)
249 #set-option -ga terminal-overrides ",gnome*:tc"
250 #set-option -g default-terminal "gnome-256color"
251 #set-option -sa terminal-overrides ",xterm*:Tc"
252 #set-option -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
253 set-option -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
254 set-option -ga terminal-overrides ",screen*:Tc"
```

in gnome-terminal text color ( without tmux )

[gnome-terminal (without tmux)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MvrX.png)

in tmux text color ( in same gnome-terminal )

[in tmux (same gnome-terminal)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmmGp.png)

i used tmux -2 -u options
but its color is little distortion
this blue color look so dark so i can read text very well